# jsp 3, jstl 1.2 and maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jstl

I use: **java 10**, **Tomcat 7.0.88** with **maven**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

*In this case I recipes following exception*

> HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
>   cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with
>   this application
>
> type Exception report
>
> message The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be
>   resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this
>   application
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri:
>   http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml
>   or the jar files deployed with this application
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:325)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:154)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:419)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:484)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1421)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     todo.TodoServlet.doGet(TodoServlet.java:23)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.88 logs. Apache Tomcat/7.0.88

Comment: Did you turn off taglib scanning in Tomcat?

Comment: Yes, it is integration problem in POM, as I think.